# Problem Connecting to a Secure Azure Service Fabric Cluster

Tags: powershell, certificate, azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to connect to a one-node cluster created successfully but so far unable to connect from the node itself or from a separate client machine.

The setup is a one node cluster where the cluster and the server/node are the same. I'm using self-signed certificates and have (in theory) installed the primary and secondary certificates on the cluster/server and an admin and standard client certificate on a client machine.

If I install an unsecure cluster on the machine, I can successfully navigate to it via a browser, but when I create a secured cluster, I'm unable to connect.

Attempting to connect via PowerShell errors with "Failed to authenticate server" identity".

Browsing to the server with Chrome just fails.

The cluster JSON config is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "SomeFancyCluster",
  "clusterConfigurationVersion": "1.0.0",
  "apiVersion": "10-2017",
  "nodes": [
    {
      "nodeName": "vm0",
      "iPAddress": "some.server.name",
      "nodeTypeRef": "NodeType0",
      "faultDomain": "fd:/dc1/r0",
      "upgradeDomain": "UD0"
    }
  ],
  "properties": {
    "diagnosticsStore": {
      "metadata": "Please replace the diagnostics file share with an actual file share accessible from all cluster machines.",
      "dataDeletionAgeInDays": "21",
      "storeType": "FileShare",
      "connectionstring": "c:\\ProgramData\\SF\\DiagnosticsStore"
    },
    "security": {
      "metadata": "The Credential type X509 indicates this is cluster is secured using X509 Certificates. The thumbprint format is - d5 ec 42 3b 79 cb e5 07 fd 83 59 3c 56 b9 d5 31 24 25 42 64.",
      "ClusterCredentialType": "Windows",
      "ServerCredentialType": "X509",
      "WindowsIdentities": {
        "ClusterIdentity": "some.server"
      },
      "CertificateInformation": {
        "ClusterCertificate": {
          "Thumbprint": "ab123456789123456789123456789123456789cd",
          "ThumbprintSecondary": "ef123456789123456789123456789123456789gh",
          "X509StoreName": "My"
        },
        "ServerCertificate": {
          "Thumbprint": "ab123456789123456789123456789123456789cd",
          "ThumbprintSecondary": "ef123456789123456789123456789123456789gh",
          "X509StoreName": "My"
        },
        "ClientCertificateThumbprints": [{
               "CertificateThumbprint": "ab123456789123456789123456789123456789ef",
               "IsAdmin": false
           }, {
               "CertificateThumbprint": "ab123456789123456789123456789123456789gh",
               "IsAdmin": true
           }]
      }
    },
    "nodeTypes": [
      {
        "name": "NodeType0",
        "clientConnectionEndpointPort": "19000",
        "clusterConnectionEndpointPort": "19001",
        "leaseDriverEndpointPort": "19002",
        "serviceConnectionEndpointPort": "19003",
        "httpGatewayEndpointPort": "19080",
        "reverseProxyEndpointPort": "30000",
        "applicationPorts": {
          "startPort": "20001",
          "endPort": "20031"
        },
        "ephemeralPorts": {
          "startPort": "20032",
          "endPort": "20287"
        },
        "isPrimary": true
      }
    ],
    "fabricSettings": [
      {
        "name": "Setup",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "FabricDataRoot",
            "value": "C:\\ProgramData\\SF"
          },
          {
            "name": "FabricLogRoot",
            "value": "C:\\ProgramData\\SF\\Log"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I've then attempted to connect, as per the docs using the following PowerShell command

```
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint some.server.name:19000 -KeepAliveIntervalInSec 10 -X509Credential -ServerCertThumbprint <Server Thumbprint> -FindType FindByThumbprint -FindValue <Client Thumbprint> -StoreLocation CurrentUser -StoreName My
```

I installed the client certificate to 'Certificates - Current User/Personal/Certificates'

On the server, the certificates are all in 'Certificates (Local Computer)/Personal/Certificates'

With the primary server/cluster certificate also in 'Certificates (Local Computer)/Trusted Root Certification Authorities' with a CN equal to some.server.name.

Any ideas as to what's missing/wrong above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling this is related to the ClusterIdentity field in the configuration. Could you tell me why did you add it?

You are authenticating by certificate so remove `WindowsIdentities` section entirely and change `ClusterCredentialType` to `X509` too if you want to connect to cluster by certificate. Update cluster configuration and you should be able to connect.

Otherwise provide `-WindowsCredential` parameter not a certificate while you are connecting.

Comment: I was just trying different configurations, so must have got mixed up, but it seems this has worked... also stupidly, one needs to ensure to use the https protocol in a browser. Thanks for your help.